# Financial Planning and Management

Tags: united-states, financial-advisor

I have a cousin that I assist with some of her business affairs and I provide some financial assistance.  She is in her late seventies and has no other close relatives.  Since she lives on the other side of the country, I can't help her with  day to day local issues.

She is contemplating appointing the trust department of a local bank as her successor trustee should she become incapacitated.  They would manage her assets, pay her bills, file tax returns, manage her daily needs, etc.

Some questions:

- How should she go about vetting them?
- How does she determine if they are capable of handling her needs?
- How does she research their reputation?
- How does one oversee their performance?  An outside family lawyer?

Please feel free to offer any additional information.  TIA

Comment: Generally, if you have to research someone, you don't make them your trustee. Family members or other people you already trust may agree to take this role. I'd say pick them the way you pick who will be the executor of your estate when that day comes.

Comment: I don't think your cousin is looking for a trustee, but someone to have durable power of attorney over her finances (maybe medical POA too). As far as I know, bank trust departments mainly handle the proper distribution of trust assets to beneficiaries, not so much day-to-day financial management.

As Keshlam said, someone your cousin already trusts would be ideal. However, knowing that your cousin doesn't have family nearby, a professional fiduciary may be a route to consider. They can be appointed to have financial and medical POA, act as conservators, administer an estate, etc.

Comment: @Stan H- Thanks for your feedback.  The problem is that she has no immediate family and her friends are in their late 70's and 80's, incapable of handling day to day affairs.  She is looking for some agency to act as a trustee for day to day matters rather than just the financial matters of her estate.

Comment: I've added a location tag based on your past activity, but you may want to add a state tag too?